# Runtime configuration of a C application for Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

We have a C application for Linux consisting of few modules. Each module can have some global config variables (some integers, strings etc.). The application is intended to run as a daemon for a long time.

What is the nicest way to reconfigure the app during run-time? Ideally, we would like to change somehow the content of those config-variables. Via `/proc`, `inotify`? What's the coolest, advanced way?

Comment: How can you use /proc for this task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sending a signal like `SIGHUP` which your program traps with a signal handler and does whatever it needs to do, like re-reading its configuration file, is a time-honored way of doing this.  I can't call it a "coolest advanced" way, rather a practical and easy way.  It is, for example, what happens when you want Apache's `httpd` daemon to re-read `httpd.conf` - it happens under the hood of `service httpd reload`.

Comment: And how to pass those values? Normally via config-file? Is /proc the kernel-only fs for that?

Comment: Example: software reloads config files on the designated signal.

Comment: @James, yes, I meant that the program should re-read its config file.  I'll update the answer to make that clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I did something similar, I simply checked the modification timestamp of the configuration file every X minutes, and if changed re-read the file. Today I would probably use `inotify` or similar native API on whatever platform I was on, even though it is more work.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually more simple, even for system administrators, to restart a server after having reconfigured it (and usually, people don't do that directly on a production machine). Or at least to have the server reload its configuration files thru a signal (like SIGHUP is often used for).

If going thru configuration files is not adequate for your needs (but usually, it is a good approach), you could consider having a more interactive interface, e.g. thru a web browser, for that goal. If you really want to go that way, you might embed a tiny web server in your application, or give it FastCGI or SCGI abilities.

Answer (score 0):

The "coolest, advanced way" would be to expose the modules as D-Bus objects (on the "system" bus), with the settings as D-Bus properties.